# Problems Distributing Visual Studio Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, camera

This is my first time with VisualStudio. 
I have to develope an application which manage a Imaging Source CAM.
The Manufacturer provides the SDK with some examples from which I can start and learn. 
Before spend time on developing my program logic I tried to compile the examples and they work great on my own machine.
So I tried to build a Setup to install the application on another PC.
I configured primary output, It included the dll dependecies (only one own dll from manufacturer) on the Setup projects. I think I done it right but when I install the application on another PC it doesn't WORK. It crashes without open any windows.
How can I find the problem? Is there any way to debug  it? Or know why it crashes? Am I doing the setup buidling in the right way?

Thanks, Federico.

Comment: Check the event viewer

Comment: I'd install the remote debugging tools, add a MessageBox.Show("attach debugger now"); to be executed as one of the first lines in your code. As soon as you see the message box, you attach the remote debugger and you should be able to figure out where the exception is thrown. Also have a look at the Application Log in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful!